How can I record my electric guitar through Zoom G3Xn processor in GarageBand without any other accessories?
The following accessories are available :

Electric guitar (Fender-Squier)
ZOOM G3Xn processor
Fender 10G Amp
Macbook with GarageBand

Also, there are various types of wires to connect such accessories. Now I need some idea for recording using them. Is the following sequel correct:

Guitar --> G3Xn --> Mac(GarageBand) ?

Is it possible to record without purchasing any audio interface like Focusrite??

If the Macbook has a physical line-in audio input connector, connect the Zoom to it with a suitable adapter cable. If the Macbook doesn't have a physical audio input, then the only possibility is to record the Fender amp acoustically with the Macbook's microphone.

Recording with computer, you’ll always get the best experience by using an interface. If you just want a quick scratch demo situation, you can use other measures.

It really depends on specific Model and generation of your MacBook. Apple had discontinued the dual mic/headphone jack several years ago for some  MacBooks so you need to check the specs of your MacBook to see if it either has a dual functioning jack or both audio out and in jacks.

As far as I can tell, Zoom G3n does not have audio interface capabilities. This means, you cannot use the USB connection for audio transmission.
If your computer has audio jack, you may try to use it, but an audio interface is probably the best option. Note, that you not only need to route audio signal from G3n into your computer, but also route sound from the computer, so that you can hear the backing track, metronome, etc.
With just one pair of outputs from G3n it might be tricky to route the signal both to the amp and to the computer (via interface). I would rather recommend using direct monitoring option in the interface to combine the input sound from G3n and the sound from the computer. You could route that to the amp, but it will likely color the sound. Headphones may give better results. Of course, studio monitors are recommended.

You can record the sound of your guitar's amp with GarageBand by using the internal mic in the Mac but a better way to record guitar is by using a digital audio interface. The interface will connect your guitar or Zoom G3X to the Mac and GarageBand. The amp's sound will not be what's recorded unless a microphone is used with the interface, not a connection from the guitar or Zoom G3X.
Your amp can be used as a monitor for the interface.  Connect one or both of the interface outputs to the audio input of your amp.  An adapter will be needed since the interface outputs will be 1/4" and the amp's input is 1/8". Headphones connected to the interface are another way to monitor the recording.  Headphones do not produce feedback.
There is a possibility that your amp output can be connected to an interface by using the headphone output and an adapter 1/8" to 1/4".
Your choices are:

Guitar > Zoom G3X > Audio Interface > Mac(GragageBand) > Audio Interface > Fender amp or headphones for monitoring

Guitar > Zoom G3X > amp > Mac recording by internal mic

Guitar > Zoom G3X > amp > external mic > interface > Mac

Guitar > Zoom G3X > amp and interface > Mac

There is a possibility you can connect the headphone output of the amp to > interface > Mac.


There are interfaces with one guitar/mic inputs, two, and more.
